# copy source and form from one pc to another and jframe form no longer works

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried to copy a source package from one pc to another. I did this by copying and pasting the source code. I see this was the wrong approach because the copy did not copy something. I have resolved these issues in the programs that did not have forms. However in the one program which uses a form I get the following message:

"The form seems to be corrupted. The GUI builder is not able to find the sections with the generated code. The special comments that denote the start and the end of these sections were removed or modified. The form will only be opened in read mode"

The result is that I cannot make modifications to the forms. I cannot go back to the original pc to do the whole process correctly, since it has crashed. How can I regenerate the lost special comments that denote the start and the end of the generated code? I compared the generated code from the original source to the generated code which I copied. I cannot see any difference.
I also researched the link http://wiki.netbeans.org/FormGuardedBlockError but did not obtain any useful information.

Comment: You should really start using a version control tool like git

Comment: It should be sufficient to copy the whole project folder, and not only the source folder.